# ASP MVC Facebook application template - whole page refresh on each link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

There is [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/13/the-new-facebook-application-template-and-library-for-asp.net-mvc.aspx) template,

If I go to another View  , it's moves to the next View , but the whole page is getting refreshed....

menining the facebook header & facebook right panel is getting refresh also which makes this template

useless , doesn't have application feeling .

Is this normal behavior? If yes , what are my options ? make 'pure' single page site ?

```
<a href="~/Home/Test" >test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the entire page from being refreshed, you have two options:

`@Ajax.ActionLink`

or place your page inside an iframe.